# Google Chrome Autofill - How to disable

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, autocomplete, autofill

I have a page to search for a address, which uses the info typed by the user to get the desired address.

Lately chrome has been showing the autofill option in the address field.
I've search throughout the web and couldnt really see a workaround that would work.
I've tried **autocomplete="off"** but with no luck

Is there any **efficient way** to prevent google chrome not only store form information but also use the autofill feature ?

**I want to do this on client side (HTML)**

Best Regards,
Rui duarte

Comment: Please check my workaround here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill/36030236#36030236